# How to amend a bash script so it downloads the API responses locally

Tags: json, bash, csv, curl

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
group=("group1" "group12" "group123" "group1234" "group12345" "group123456") 
for group in "${group[@]}" 
do 
   curl -v GET https://websitehere.com/api/v2/groups/${group}/details -H "Authorization: Bearer PANDA TOKEN HERE" 
done
```

I want to amend the script so I can download the API responses locally. CSV or JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Use `-o, --output <file> : Write to file instead of stdout` :

```
#!/bin/bash

group=("group1" "group12" "group123" "group1234" "group12345" "group123456") 

for group in "${group[@]}" 
do 
   curl -v GET https://websitehere.com/api/v2/groups/${group}/details -H "Authorization: Bearer PANDA TOKEN HERE" -o ${group}.json
done
```

Or CSV you can use `jq` and `>` operator to redirect the output to a file :

```bash
curl -v GET https://websitehere.com/api/v2/groups/${group}/details -H "Authorization: Bearer PANDA TOKEN HERE" | jq -r '.[] | @csv' > ${group}.csv
```